# Connect to SQL Express After Changing Computer Name and User Name

Tags: sql-server

I have been running SQL Express on my local machine as part of a development environment for web development, but due to corporate requirements, recently had to change the computer name to join the new company domain. I also had to change my login/username as part of this process.

Because of this, I am no longer able to connect to my SQL Express instance, which i need to continue development. How can I migrate the existing SQL instance, which I connected to via Windows Authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let SQL Server engine works with `Local System Account`

as next:-

- Press `Window` Button + `R`.
- Type `services.msc` , then click `Ok`.
- Select SQL Server Service , then choose `properties`.

[image]

- Go to second tab `Log On` , then check `Local System Account`

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I access this screen through the services as you suggest, these options are all greyed out and I am unable to select any of them. This is also true of the "Run, Stop, Start, Restart" options in the context menu.

Comment: I did open the services as administrator, and do have administrator privileges on my machine

Comment: I was able to log in to the local machine with my old account and make this change as suggested. Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try **.\SQLEXPRESS** instead of **YourComputerName\SQLEXPRESS** in server name.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. As the solution above worked for me, I haven't been able to try this one, but it looks like a viable solution as well.